# boost::log (boost logging): BOOST_LOG_FUNCTION only works in main thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-log, boost-logging

Consider the following function:

```
void thread() 
{ 
    BOOST_LOG_FUNCTION(); 

    while(true) {
        // Create log entry
    }
}
```

If I just call "thread()" within "main" my log entries created in "thread()" look as expected:

```
 [void __cdecl thread(void) (c:\...\maintest.cpp:16)]
```

However if you use "thread()" within a function:

```
 boost::thread t(thread);
```

the appropriate log-entry is empty:

```
[]
```

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got feedback from the boost log author. To make the scope available within the loggin process you have to add "Scope" as an attribute. It did this:

```
logging::core::get()->add_thread_attribute("Scope", attrs::named_scope());
```

However, this is only related to the current thread as indicated. If you are using multiple threads you have to call:

```
logging::core::get()->add_global_attribute("Scope", attrs::named_scope());
```